# Getting new IDs after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, identity

I'm inserting a bunch of new rows into a table which is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [sometable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [someval] sometype NOT NULL
)
```

using the following insert:

```
insert into sometable select somefield as someval from othertable
```

when I've finished, I'd like to know the IDs of all the newly inserted rows. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only returns the ID last row inserted.

How can I get all the new IDs?

One method that springs to mind would be to grab the current largest identity from sometable and the scope_identity() post-insert, and use these two values to select from sometable. For example:

```
declare @currentMaxId int;
select @currentMaxId=MAX(id) from sometable
insert into sometable select somefield as someval from othertable
select * from sometable where id>@currentMaxId and id<=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Is there a better pattern?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use the OUTPUT functionality to grab all the INSERTED Id back into a table.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    MyPK INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MyColumn NVARCHAR(1000)
)

DECLARE @myNewPKTable TABLE (myNewPK INT)

INSERT INTO 
    MyTable
(
    MyColumn
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.MyPK INTO @myNewPKTable
SELECT
    sysobjects.name
FROM
    sysobjects

SELECT * FROM @myNewPKTable
```

Comment: @Robin - I've been working with SQL Server for years, but I learned two new things from your answer, OUTPUT, and the TABLE datatype.  Thanks.

Comment: I've also been using SQL for probably 15 years and had no idea OUTPUT existed, thanks!

Comment: @Robin, this question may sound silly, but if I retrieve this primarykey value in the table 'myNewPkTable' inside a loop (cursor in this case), this value is going to be inserted in a row inside that table, yes?

Comment: This is *the* solution..... until the table contains a trigger, then you run into a bug that Microsoft refuses to fix (`OUTPUT` cannot be used without `INTO` in a table with a trigger, and gives wrong values when `INTO` is used). The explanation and a possible workaround (for the `UPDATE` case at least) are listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13198476/2557263

Comment: if anyone out there also has issues understanding @robinDay's answer. This post could be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Robin Day's answer -- you can map your temp Id's to the new Id's using a `MERGE` trick.

```
DECLARE @Keys TABLE (TempId INT, RealId INT)

MERGE MyTable
    USING @NewStuff t
    ON 1 = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (col1, col2, col3)
        VALUES (t.col1, t.col2, t.col3)
        OUTPUT t.TempId, Inserted.RealId INTO @Keys
```

From @Ivan Starostin's clever answer here:
[List of inserted ID in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612195/list-of-inserted-id-in-sql-server?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

And if you want the "control" in ADO.Net and get the ids assigned to childs and getting the ids back so that you can update your model:
http://daniel.wertheim.se/2010/10/24/c-batch-identity-inserts/

Comment: Link no longer works. Site still works but only via https and site history doesn't go beyond 11/06/2010.

Comment: Google cached version https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iVqxMunQvOMJ:https://danielwertheim.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/c-batch-identity-inserts/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 0):

User this stored Procuedure

this will be a dynamic primary key..

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
```

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_BulkInsertCountry
(
@FilePath varchar(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN--PROCEDURE
--variable declaration
declare @SQL varchar(500)
declare @id int
declare @CountryName varchar(30)

--Create temporary table for Country
CREATE TABLE #tmpCountry
(
CountryName varchar(30),
)

---executing bulk insert on temporary table
SET @SQL='BULK INSERT #tmpCountry from ''' + @FilePath + ''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='','',ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'')'
EXEC(@sql)

DECLARE cursor_Country CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
select [CountryName] from #tmpCountry

OPEN cursor_Country
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Country INTO @CountryName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
SELECT @id=isnull(max(Countryid),0) from tblCountryMaster
SET @id=@id+1
INSERT INTO tblCountryMaster values(@Id,@CountryName) 
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Country INTO @CountryName
END
CLOSE cursor_Country
DEALLOCATE cursor_Country
END--PROCEDURE

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

For More details visit following link
http://jalpesh.blogspot.com/search?q=bulk+insert

Answer (score 0):

create a table to set all the new IDs.
then make a loop for all the insert.
inside the loop make the insert you want with SCOPE_IDENTITY().
after the insert get the new ID and insert it into the new table you created for.
in the end select * from [newTable].