# List of inserted ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert, output, identity

I have a table variable

```
@temp (tmpId, c1, c2, c3, d1, d2, d3)
```

I want to insert rows from @temp to a table (MyTable) having identity column called ID and assign the isnerted IDs to the rows in @temp. I know that the list of inserted ids can be retrieve using OUTPUT clause.

```
INSERT INTO MyTABLE (c1, c2, c3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id, INSERTED.c1, ... INTO @IDs (id, c1, ...)
SELECT (c1, c2, c3)
```

Dispite having @IDs table I can not assigne the inserted ids to the tmpIds because the c1, c2, c3 columns are not unique. I need the Ids to insert d1, d2, d3 columns to another table.
I have only one solution in my mind. Inserting rows one by one and retrieving id with SCOPE_IDENTITY(). But I'd like to aviod using loop.
Any idea how to insert these rows in one step?

Comment: Do you have a primary key/unique constraint defined on `c1, c2, c3 ` columns one @temp ? Did you used a table valued type to declare this variable of did you used following syntax `DECLARE @temp TABLE (...)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try merge trick with linking source rows with inserted identity values:

```
merge MyTABLE t
using @temp s
on 1=0
when not mathed then
insert ...
output inserted.ID, s.tempID 
into @linked_ids(id1, id2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue couple days ago and finally I used different, we can say insert from ordered select, approach. Because we did not want to use merge.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTABLE (c1, c2, c3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id, INSERTED.c1, ... INTO @IDs (id, c1, ...)
SELECT (c1, c2, c3) ORDER BY tmpId
```

So the order of `INSERTED.id` should be guaranteed now and directed by the order of tmpId (because of insert from ordered select `ORDER BY tmpId`). It means tmpId must be something like order in collection inside caller application.

It looks that works well.

PS: another approach, when you don't use merge and ordered select is extend table by something like `requestId` and store input id to the table and return to caller application.